# Compatibility Mode button still there even with IE=edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

According to HTML5 Boilerplate, I would expect the following included `meta` tag to remove the Compatibility Mode button from IE8:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

But when I view my site in IE8, the compatibility mode button is still there. I want my site to work in IE8 and above and I do not want my visitor's IE browsers to show a compatibility mode button. The problem is that if someone clicks it by accident and turns on Compatibility mode in an IE8 browser, then my page doesn't render correctly because of weird IE7 quirks.

So how do I turn off the button?

EDIT:

Here is the beginning of my `head` tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
```

It's the same as default H5BP. I have also tried moving the compat. mode meta tag to be the first tag in `<head>` with no difference.

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a response header instead of a meta tag? Can we also see your complete HTML head? I seem to recall reading something about this needing to appear first.

Comment: [Here's a link](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/doc/html.md#x-ua-compatible) to the documentation in general as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been going on for a long time (https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1187). I use this (modify the classes below the doctype for your needs):

http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-conditional-classnames-for-hack-free-css/

```
<!--[if IE ]><![endif]-->
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="no-js lt-ie10 ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually moved all the IE conditional code to the `<body>` tag instead of the HTML tag and that fixed the problem as well.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could do that but my CMS uses the body and I didn't want to confuserize the people using it.

Comment: What is the difference in your conditional comments above that fixes the original bug that was in the H5BP comments?

Comment: Wow fast response. Thanks!